# phpexcel corrupt file export to browser: we found a problem with some content

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having issues opening exported excel file.

I was having the same issue earlier and I had to store it to some path first, and then read the file and write it to the output buffer.

That worked with no issues on my local machine.

But the same issue occurred in the server.

Here's what I did earlier:

```
    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $lsFileName = isset($file_name) && $file_name != null ? $file_name.'.xlsx' : 'Report.xlsx';
    $upload_dir = "upload/export_dump/";

    if(is_dir($upload_dir) == false) {
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777);
    }

    $lsSavePath = $upload_dir.$lsFileName;

    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->save($lsSavePath);

    $lnFilesize = filesize($lsSavePath);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . utf8_decode($lsFileName));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header("Content-Length:" . $lnFilesize);
    readfile($lsSavePath);
```

EDIT: I tried checking if any outputs are made prior to reading file.

```
    .
    .
    header("Content-Length:" . $lnFilesize);
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    if(!empty($output)) {
        var_dump($output);
        die('Something was definitely printed!');
    } else {
        readfile($lsSavePath);    
    }
```

But the file gets downloaded, and the same repair message pops up.

NOTE: On downloading the file from the server itself (not through browser) and opening the file, there is no issue.

Comment: Make sure no other output is sent to the browser, like warnings, notices, blank spaces, ...

Comment: @DarkBee, alright.. but there's no issue on my local device.. does this make any difference?

Comment: The error reporting level can be higher on the live server, thus showing strict notices, warnings, deprecated functionsbe cause of another php version...

Comment: @DarkBee I checked the output buffer prior to readfile(), and it seems empty. I have updated the post. Please check.

Comment: @DarkBee forgot to mention.. I have integrated chart into the excel file.. don't know if that makes difference..

Comment: Have you tried to open the downloaded file from Notepad or some other plain-text viewer - to confirm there are no error messages inside the file ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I tried opening the file with Notepad.. there was no error on opening but found the problem : the whole page is being exported, i.e. with html and js